# API authentication design

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, go, architecture

I'm planning on building a web service consisting of two servers - an API backend (RESTful & stateless) and a web server frontend. The backend will be build with Go and the web server with PHP or Java.

Basically I'd like multiple users to log in with their web browsers through the use of their facebook or google credentials which I understand I must use OAuth for.

I'm however deeply confused about how I should design the authentication. 
Can I simply implement OAuth on the webserver alone and then use an API-key/secret to validate the webserver with my API and communicate over an encrypted connection between the two of them. Would that be secure and work just fine or should I implement authentication in some other way?

I've made a simple diregram showing my idea of how this could be done.

[image: Authentication diagram]

I really hope that you guys can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two common approached to tacking the problem:

**Trusted subsystem model vs Delegation model**

**Trusted subsystem**

Use a trusted subsystem model, it maybe impractical to maintain a separate key and secret for every user of the front end, the trusted subsystem model basically states that a system (web server) with authority to an api is responsible or trusted to authenticate/authorise users access to that api, and is given authority to do so.

What you do is provision a account for the web server, and allow the web server to authorize access to the api.

**Delegation model**

If you have control over how the api authenticates you can use the same method as the frontend and reuse the end users security principal to authenticate to the back end api.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. My question is how do I trust the web server. How does it authenticate itself to the API. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "trusted subsystem model". Could you please explain in a bit more depth? Is my solution a bit impractical as you say but still safe?

Comment: With trusted subsys model The web server is treated as a super user and given an account to use the api, the web server is then responsible for given access to the end users as appropriate.

Comment: So basically what I've painted in my diagram?

Comment: Yes exactly, however one disadvantage of the TSM model if the web server is compromised the end user could have direct api in a bad way. Delegation model is more inline with a defense in depth approach where each layer is authenticating each request from its source user

Comment: The way you propose is totally valid, as long as your web app is robust and fails safe, remember to keep the vulnerabilities in mind.

Comment: Okay. :) So to make sure that I understand the delegation model. If I choose to use the delegation model I would have OAuth both between my web server and the client(web browser) AND between my API and the web server?

Comment: Oauth is a authorization technology which can be to get way with authentication, take a look at http://oauth.net/articles/authentication, to understand it, You could use openid or openid connect instead which is oauth 2 with authentication. :)